# Error while updating the pulled project in IntelliJ

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I am trying to make the transition from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA. Now so far I havev been working on the project at work using Eclipse and that worked fine, with pulling the project using SVN Tortoise then importing the project as an existing Maven project.

Now in IntelliJ, I choose Subversion to pull the project so that I may work on it.
The problem is as follows. When I try to start the project using the maven scripts that are made with the project I get the following error message

```
Provider message:
The svn command failed.
Command output:
svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
svn: E155036: The working copy at 'C:\workspace_IntelJ\satec\trunk'
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
is too old (format 29) to work with client version '1.9.4-SlikSvn (SlikSvn/1.9.4)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.
```

This in its self is not a problem. I followed the instructions and tried to update the project. But upon executing the command this shows up.

```
svn: E200030: sqlite[S1]: duplicate column name: inherited_props, executing statement 'ALTER TABLE NODES ADD COLUMN inherited_props BLOB; '
```

And I can't seem to be able to locate it on the internet. Or perhaps I am searching for the wrong things. Either way I can't update the project because of this error.

Thank you in advance! If I was not clear enough I will edit it to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Try the **VCS**|**Refresh File Status** menu option.  It cleared up the problem in my environment.  I originally got this error when I switched from SVN 1.7 to 1.8 (using TortoiseSVN) after checking out my project with SVN 1.7.